# Is this SpecFlow scenario correct?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, specflow, gherkin

This is my first more "complex" SpecFlow scenario written in Gherkin. Please provide me any feedback about it's quality:

```
Scenario: CompanyUpload
    Given admin (user) log in to admin-site
    When user enters Uploading page
    And user downloads Company Upload template
    And template is updated by script
    And user opens Company upload form
    And user fills it with proper data
    And user submit filled form
    Then new job should be added to the queue (visible in table form)
    And job status should be "In Queue" for not longer than 10 minutes
    And job status should be updated to "Processing" and shouldn't take more than 4 minutes
    And final job status should be "Succeeded"
```

This scenario is already coded with Selenium Webdriver actions. Now, I would like to cover it with SpecFlow to create acceptance tests library.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not really about programming, it belongs on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), if anywhere

Comment: @SamHolder And what code would we review?

Comment: @Pimgd are you saying that this question is a valid question for stackoverflow? as as far as I can see there is not problem with the code, its just asking to review the quality of the scenario, which is code. As I said, IMHO code review is a better fit than here

Comment: @SamHolder You might be right, I'm not sure. We get a lot of off-topic stuff, I took a look at the question, thought I saw no code and made that comment. Now I look again and I see that it's actually english-style pseudo code parsed by an interpreter... ... it's code, alright, but we have 0 specflow questions... it might work on Code Review, it might also never get answered due to lack of audience. The idea is good, I'm just worried it won't get answered.

Comment: @Pimgd its already been answered (with a decent answer which I've upvoted), but that still doesn't make it a good question for SO. I don't know if migrating it would be right (hence the *if anywhere*), and I suspect it won't get closed here, as this tag doesn't really get enough traffic, but I still felt obligated to point out the OP that its not really a good question for here. I suspect the OP won't care either way now he has a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

Features should focus on **behavior** not on implementation. So putting incidental detail in your features is not a good idea. In your example I'd say that your when steps are somewhat fragmented. Instead using 6 when steps to describe **how** the user uploads something, use one or two to describe **what** the user does. For instance.

```
When user uploads document using company upload template
```

Something like this describes the necessary detail but not more than that.